# Wrapping react-leaflet Map componet in <div> tag makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am attempting to add a sibling `<DeviceControls/>` component alongside my `<MapContainer/>` component. But when when I do so the OpenStreetMap / Leaflet map disappears from the DOM and all that shows on the page is the contents of the `<DeviceControls/>`component.

This is especially confusing as I appear to be doing the same thing as the offfical examples from PaulLeCam/react-leaflet (https://github.com/blob/70cd9f32bb6461df65b0d07b9810d5e9ddf459ad/example/components/index.js)

```
const examples = (
  <div>
    <h1>React-Leaflet examples</h1>
    <h2>Popup with Marker</h2>
    <SimpleExample />
    <h2>Events</h2>
    <p>Click the map to show a marker at your detected location</p>
      ...
    <EventsExample />
    <h2>WMS tile layer</h2>
    <WMSTileLayerExample />
  </div>
)
```

Where there are many React components alongside many Map components and they all display on the page fine.

Can anyone see why it doesn't work when I try this same thing? ie why does wrapping my `<MapContainer/>` in a `<div>` make the `<MapCOntainer/>` component seem to disappear in my code but not the official example code?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer />    
            <DeviceControls />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: In Chrome react inspector, is it still in the DOM? <MapContainer/> ?

Comment: Yes I can still see <MapContainer /> in the React dev tools http://imgur.com/a/ZoMVq

Answer (score 3):

The was happening because the `<div>` wrapping the `<MapContainer />`
 `<DeviceControls />` needs a height set on it. Changing it to `<div style={{ height: '100%'>` solves this problem.